# How to isolate group from computers by L3 switch from certain www?

Tags: switch, vlan, qos

There is a broken switch to replace and I need to buy new one. I decide on this model: https://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-LGS528/ 
Is it possible to isolate 24 computers that are connected to this switch from certain www adresses (games, youtube, adult sites, etc...) and leave 2 ports untouched at this switch? Are there any other model or solution to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to isolate 24 computers that are connected to this switch from certain www adresses (games, youtube, adult sites, etc...) and leave 2 ports untouched at this switch?

No - this is the job of a purpose-build product, [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server), or *possibly* a firewall with [Deep Packet Inspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection) (though the feature set will be very limited).

A layer 3 switch won't even look at the traffic content at this level.

Note that with the increasing use of [SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) ([HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)), the task of filtering is becoming more and more difficult without installing a certificate on each client device or training users to click through certificate errors. Neither of these are good options.